# Maximum call stack size exceeded when calculating FormGroup Field

Tags: angular, typescript

I’m trying to create a form with angular/typescript where fields get calculated automatically according to what number is in another field. So, for example we have Areasize_divided which should be the value of the field Areasize but divided by 100. And Areasize which is Areasize_divided mutliplied by 100

currently i get the following error

> ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

This is my form group:

```
formGroup = new FormGroup({
        Buildyear:           new FormControl(this.buildyear, [Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(4)]),
        Areasize:            new FormControl(this.areasize, [Validators.required] ),
        Areasize_divided:    new FormControl(''),
     });
```

This is my HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
         <input type="number"
         matInput
         formControlName="Areasize"
         placeholder="Area Size"
         (input)="calcAreaSize()"
         />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input type="number"
        matInput
        formControlName="Areasize_divided"
        placeholder="Area Size Divided"
        (input)="calcAreaSizeDivided()"
        />
     </mat-form-field>
```

And this is my TS where the two functions are called:

```
calcAreasize_divided()
    {
        this.formGroup.get('Areasize')
            .valueChanges
            .subscribe(value => this.formGroup
                .get('Areasize_divided')
                .setValue(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value / 100)
        );      
    }

calcAreasize()
    {
        this.formGroup.get('Areasize_divided')
            .valueChanges
            .subscribe(value => this.formGroup
                .get('Areasize')
                .setValue(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value * 100)
        );     
    }
```

Is there any other way I could do this? I tried doing it onInit() but I get the same error.

Comment: Please consider creating a stackblitz for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are changing the another input value in one input change and it causes stack full, so you can do it this way:

```
  export class AppComponent  {
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  public buildyear=0;
  public areasize=0;


  constructor(){
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
        Buildyear:           new FormControl(this.buildyear, [Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(4)]),
        Areasize:            new FormControl(this.areasize, [Validators.required] ),
        Areasize_divided:    new FormControl(''),
     });
  }
  calcAreasizeDivided(){
            let value = this.formGroup.controls['Areasize'].value;
        this.formGroup
                .get('Areasize')
                .setValue(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value / 100)   
    }
calcAreasize(){
        let value = this.formGroup.controls['Areasize_divided'].value;
      this.formGroup.get('Areasize_divided').setValue(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value * 100) 
    }
}
```

html:

```
<form  [formGroup]="formGroup">
<mat-form-field>
         <input type="number"
         matInput
         formControlName="Areasize"
         placeholder=""
         (input)="calcAreasize()"
         />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input type="number"
        matInput
        formControlName="Areasize_divided"
        placeholder=""
        (input)="calcAreasizeDivided()"
        />
     </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-djfmtf).